# Adding a simple nested field to object

Tags: javascript

I know this is very basic but i just can't solve it.
I simply need to add a field to an object inside an object.

```
   var shipping = {}
   shipping["only"]["price"]  = $(this).val();
```

Keep saying that i `can't set price of undefined`.

Everywhere i checked, i am allowed to do this *nested* assignment.

Comment: means `shipping["only"]` is undefined.  And looking at your shipping object, there is no properties in it.

Comment: try this :var shipping = {only:{}}
            shipping["only"]["price"]  = $(this).val();

Comment: What is the problem with ```shipping.only = {price : $(this}.val()};``` ?

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi because i dont want to override .only, it might be already exist, or might not, and i want to update it.

Comment: so you can: ```shipping.only = { ...shipping.only, price: $(this).val() }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the semantics wrong for what your code means. This:

```
shipping["only"]["price"] = $(this).val();
```

...sort of translates to:

1. Evaluate `$(this).val()` (we'll call this `R` for the sake of convenience)
2. Evaluate `shipping["only"]` (we'll call this `O`)
3. Assign the `price` property of `O` to the value `R`.

On step 2, because `shipping` is the value `{}`, `shipping["only"]` is `undefined`, and this is why you get the error that it can't assign to the property `price` of `undefined`.

If your intent is to create an object `only` property and set the `price` value of that new object, you'll want to do something more like:

```
const shipping = {
  only: {
    price: $(this).val()
  }
};
```

...or you can do two assignment statements, one to populate `.only` and then one to populate the sub-property:

```
shipping.only = {};
shipping.only.price = $(this).val();
```

Comment: thanks Jacob, the thing is that this object is dynamic and global, and i don't want to rewrite it , just to add a field. How can i add a field to an existing object without override it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Perhaps you mean you don't know whether a property already exists or not? If that's the case, check if the property exists before overwriting. For example `shipping.only = shipping.only || {}`, or the less esoteric `if (!shipping.only) shipping.only = {};`

Answer (score 1):

You can use defineProperty()

```
var shipping = {}

Object.defineProperty( shipping, 'only', {

    value: { price: $(this).val() },
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true

});
```