# Why you can add a nested field but not root field to an object?

Tags: javascript

It is basic, but i don't get it.

```
var test = {};
test["hello"] = {"love":"me"}  //*** this is not allowed because there is no hello
```

So i have to create first a property :

```
test.hello = test.hello || {};
```

Ok , this is clear, but now if i do this - **it is allowed** :

```
test.hello.world = "Hello world!";
```

But there is no `world` property inside, **what was not allowed to do in the previous case**,  why here it can be done ?

Only the root property have to be existed ?

Comment: It is allowed in the first case...

Comment: it is not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029263/adding-a-simple-nested-field-to-object/62029753#62029753

Comment: Man, you are doing something wrong your example `test.hello = "xx"` is perfectly fine and it works.

Comment: `test.hello = "xx"` is essentially the same as inserting value `"xx"` at key `hello` on object `test`

Comment: @paulseems Even after you edited the question, it's still allowed.

Comment: People explained to me here , why its not : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029263/adding-a-simple-nested-field-to-object/62029753#62029753

Comment: It's only not allowed if you are trying to do something like `test.hello.hi` or `test["hello"]["hi"]`.

Comment: thanks, thats exactly the question - why ? can you post an answer explaining why i make a mess here and whats allowed? :)

Comment: @paulseems I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only not access properties on `undefined` or `null`. For example, this code works

```js
const obj = {};
obj.prop = "value";
```

but this one doesn't

```js
const num = undefined; // Could be also null
num.prop = "value";
```

Makes sense, right?

---

An attempt to access a non-existent property *in an object* returns `undefined`.

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(obj.abc); // Logs "undefined"
```

---

So when you do `obj.abc.def = "value";`, it gets evaluated as `(obj.abc).def = "value";`, which evaluates to `undefined.def = "value";`, which is invalid because it's not possible to access properties on `undefined`.

Same thing happens when you try to get the property.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not allowed? If I do this:

```
var test = {};
test.hello = "xx"
```

It will indeed create a property called `hello` with the value `"xx"`.

```
test.hello.world = "xx" // Not possible because test.hello is undefined
test.hello = {} // Not undefined anymore, now it's an object
test.hello.world = "yay" // This is possible because test.hello is an object now
```

I hope this clarifies a bit!

Comment: I see. so i must have the previous level not empty. Ok i will accept this answer when they let me. thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your first case does not work because you are using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), I guess.

```js
'use strcit'
// Assignment to a new property on a non-extensible object
var fixed = {};
fixed.newProp = 'ohai'; // throws a TypeError
```

Comment: "throws a `TypeError`" Um... No it doesn't.